# Caesar Code program not working for letter 'Z'. What's wrong here?

Tags: c, arrays, if-statement, encryption, char

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char a[50];
    gets(a);

    for(int i=0;i<a[i];i++)
    {
        if(a[i]=="z")  //should print a for z
            printf("a");
        else if (a[i]=="Z") //should print A for Z
            printf("A");
        else if(a[i]<="Z"||a[i]<="z") //else print other char+1
            printf("%c", a[i]+1);

    }
}
```

This code doesn't return A when a[i]==Z. It returns { for z and [ for Z. What's possibly wrong here? Why isn't the if-else statement working?

Comment: Double quotes are for strings.  For characters, use single quotes.

Comment: Read the warnings from the compiler

Comment: Also, is the last else-if condition required?

Comment: `i<a[i]` is a very strange loop condition. Are you sure you want to do this and not, say, loop until the end of the string?

Comment: @Kevin I haven't learnt to do that yet

Comment: @brownputin then when do you expect the loop to end?

Comment: Stop using `gets()`! It's dangerous and has been removed from the language.

Comment: The last `else if` should be `else if (isalpha(a[i]))`

Comment: Yes, and the last condition is needed because the message might contain punctuation or other non-alpha characters, so it needs *another* `else` too. `else printf("%c", a[i]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition in the for loop

```
for(int i=0;i<a[i];i++)
```

does not make sense. For example the user can enter any symbol that will be placed in a position in the array that (the symbol) will have less value than the value of the position. In this case the loop will be interrupted.

It seems you mean

```
for ( int i = 0; a[i] != 0; i++ )
```

Also the function `gets` is unsafe and not supported by the C Standard. Instead use the standard C function `fgets`. For example

```
fgets(a, sizeof( a ), stdin );
```

In condition Within if statements you are using string literals as for example `"Z"` instead of characters as `'Z'`

So rewrite the if statements at least like

```
    if( a[i] == 'z')  //should print a for z
        putchar( 'a');
    else if (a[i] == 'Z') //should print A for Z
        putchar( 'A');
    else if( ( 'A' <= a[i] && a[i] < 'Z' )|| 
               ( 'a' <= a[i] && a[i] < 'z' ) ) //else print other char+1
        putchar( a[i] + 1 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Double quotes create strings (arrays of `char`), but `a[i]` is a `char`. You can't compare a `char` with a string. You need to use single quotes to create a `char` literal.

```
        if(a[i]=='z')  //should print a for z
            printf("a");
        else if (a[i]=='Z') //should print A for Z
            printf("A");
        else if(isalpha(a[i])) //other letters print char+1
            printf("%c", a[i]+1);
        else // everything else stays the same
            printf("%c", a[i]);
```